# How do I set up a functional chat box layout with ruby on rails after I have gotten juggernaut to work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chatroom, juggernaut, faye

I just finished implementing juggernaut.  I ran both the redis server and juggernaut and they work fine.  I have tested out the local host using irb and texts do appear.

I've basically followed the steps on github:
https://github.com/maccman/juggernaut

But now I would like to build the view with ruby on rails and actually be able to use/test the chat room like an actual chat room on any given website instead of writing messages through irb.

Should I use scaffolding to build the layout/view? Thanks!

I wish I could post up my screenshots but I don't have a high enough reputation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Railscast #260](http://railscasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye) deals with a similar topic however Ryan chose to use Faye as the messaging server. However it should be easy for you to adapt to the example chat application he builds.

There is a link to the [project source on GitHub](https://github.com/ryanb/railscasts-episodes/tree/master/episode-260/) here and a [text version of the screencast](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye) here.

Scaffolding may be useful to you here however it may be difficult to stick strictly to the REST conventions, I would attempt to use Rails for the creation of messages and then use Juggernaut to update the messages client side after creation.

Comment: "We’ve already implemented some of the functionality and have a page with a text field that we can type a message into. The message is then added to the chat window via JavaScript and AJAX when we click ‘send’."
How exactly would I implement that functionality and text field @Devin M

Comment: Look at the source code for the application, all the code is there.

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out. I just need to scaffold up a table and use JQuery for instantaneous posts.